# How do I allow a non-absolute URI in xmllint?

Tags: xml, xmllint

When I xmllint my XML file I get the following error:

```
my/path/myXmlFile.xml:2: namespace warning : xmlns: URI some.thing is not absolute
```

My app needs these kind of paths. I searched in the man pages of xmllint but could not find any arguments for my problem. How do I turn this validation error off?

Comment: The only reason that the value of an `xmlns` value has to be an absolute URI is to limit the risk of people putting things in the same namespace by accident (since you only create namespaces for domains that you control). If you need to have a relative URI there, then you are using `xmlns` incorrectly in the first place. Fix the root cause (don't abuse `xmlns`) instead of trying to hack `xmlns` into doing something it isn't supposed to do.

Comment: I have government supplied XML file with relative namespaces screws all sorts of things up.

Answer (score 0):

It'a long history: namespace URI must be valid URL with protocol identifier (http:// , https:// , etc.)

https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#sec-intro

You can suppress the warning with the `--nowarning` option to `xmllint` command.

```
xmllint --xpath "//Envelope/Body/CompanySearchResponse/CompanyList/CompanyItem" --nowarning risp.xml
```